# Vertical Grid Support Fragment loses position when scrolling

Tags: android, kotlin, gridview, android-tv

An application is created in which I use Vertical Grid Support Fragment.
I have 30 elements and they do not fit on the screen, and they can be scrolled down.
You can also select and save these elements, but when I select an element and scroll below, when I return to the selected element from above, it changes its position or ceases to be selected.
I tried a lot of everything that helped earlier. Tried to override methods:

```
override fun getItemId (position: Int): Long {
return position.toLong ()
}

override fun getItemViewType (position: Int): Int {
reverse position
}
```

I tried to get something similar, but nothing came of it. Help!(